# awk to compare two files, extract, output to third

Tags: scripts

I've written a script in Python, but it's not fast enough for this job.
 I'm thinking line-by-line processing would work better.

I have two files with two columns and potentially hundreds of millions of lines (bioinformatics). The two files (file1, file2) are similar, tab-delimited, with the first column containing strings of letters and numbers and the second column containing integers.  The headers are `name`, `count` in each file.

I need to produce a tab-delimited file where: the first entry of each row is from the `name` column, but only those names that are in both `file1` and `file2`, the second entry is the `count` for that `name` from file 1; and the third entry is the `count` for that `name` from `file2`,  preserving headers.

After much reading, here is my attempt:

```
awk '(NR == FNR) {
   n0[$1] = 0; 
   n1[$1] = 0; 
   next
 }     {
   if($1 in n0) {
     n2[$2] = 0
   }
 } END {
   for (i in n0) (j in n1) (k in n2) {
     print i,"\t",j,"\t",k
   } 
}' file1 file2
```

so clearly I don't really know what I'm doing with creating arrays (I'm not sure they can be two-dimensional so I tried to use three).

If someone could correct the awk script using the same basic flow syntax as in the above, that would be excellent and much appreciated.

also, to convert it to an executable .sh file, what should be done?

from  the elements of the first column of the two files (only those elements which are present in both of the two files find the intersection of values between the two files in the first column, and then

Comment: I'm sure you can do much better.  I read the files into a dataframe, extracted columns into dictionaries, then went from there.

Comment: How would you do it line by line with Python?

Answer (score 3):

You would be much better off if your input is sorted on the first column, since then you can directly use the [`join`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/join.1) command:

```
$ cat foo 
a   1
b   2
c   3
d   4
$ cat bar
b   1
d   4
e   5
n   2
$ join -t $'\t' <(sort foo) <(sort bar)                                                                                                            
b   2   1
d   4   4
```

In any case, I'd recommend sorting - without sorting, you're potentially looking at `O(m*n)` operations, but with sorting, `O(m*log(m) + n*log(n) + min(m,n))` operations - it should save you a while if you optimize your methods instead of the language you use.

With `awk`, you can get away with a single array:

```
awk 'NR==FNR { n[$1] = $2; next } ($1 in n) {print $1, n[$1], $2}' foo bar
```

This should be reasonably fast as well, if `$i in n` is.

Comment: Just a note, it's `min(m,n)`. If the smallest set is exhausted there's nothing more to compare

Comment: @kos looks like my brain is on holiday. :D

Comment: @muru +1 for "divide et impera" anyway :D

Comment: ok, that seems like a great option.  However, any chance of getting this to work with an awk command of the type I tried initially?

Comment: @Matt if you must use awk, I have added an awk alternative as well.

Comment: hey, great, I see it now.

Comment: if you don't mind another question, what is n[$1] = $2 doing?

Comment: @Matt saving the value of second field to the array `n`, with the value of first field as index.

Comment: ok, I think I understand arrays better now.  and a final question: how would you get a first line: Name count1 count2 in the output using the awk framework? would you use a BEGIN phrase before NR=FNR?

Comment: @Matt yes, I'd put `BEGIN {print "Name","count1","count2"}`.

Answer (score 2):

With `bash`:

Assuming `file1`:

```
abc123 123456
def456 789123
ghi789 456789
```

And `file2`:

```
abc123 789123
```

This will output `file3`:

```
abc123 123456 789123
```

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while read line1; do
    var1=$(echo $line1 | tr '\t' '\n')
    while read line2; do
        var2=$(echo $line2 | tr '\t' '\n')
        if [ "${var1[0]}" == "${var2[0]}" ]; then
            printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "${var1[0]}" "${var1[1]}" "${var1[2]}"
        fi
    done < file2
done < file1
```

Comment: The output expected is a bit different:  "the second entry is the count for that name from file 1; and the third entry is the count for that name from file2"

Comment: @muru It's not clear actually: how I interpreted this at first was "the second entry is the count (meaning the value under the header named "count", not a sum) for that name [taken] from [that line in] file1; and the third entry is the count (meaning the value under the header named "count", not a sum) for that name [taken] from [that line in] file 2", but now I'm not sure.

Comment: Indeed! I didn't see that column is named count.

Comment: @muru It's not clear tough, anyway I meant it to be run in `bash`, I used the wrong Shebang though

Comment: Even with bash, I'd strongly recommend printf over echo.

Comment: @muru Didn't know it's not safe. Rolled back

Comment: @Matt You're welcome, anyway check out muru's answer as well and maybe combine the two toghether like `sort data1 > file1 && sort data2 > file2 && ./script.sh`, it's dependent on the dataset but sorting in the average case speeds up things quite a bit